# Converting a double scripted array of grayscale int values to a BufferedImage

Tags: java, bufferedimage

So after hours of searching I am ready to pull my hair out on this one.

I am doing some research in Computer Vision and am working with grayscale images. I need to end up with an "image" (a double scripted double array) of Sobel filtered double values. My Sobel converter is set up to take in a double scripted int array (int[][]) and go from there.

I am reading in a buffered image and I gather the grayscale int values via a method that I am 99% sure works perfectly (I can present it if need be).

Next I am attempting to convert this matrix of int values to a BufferedImage by the below method:

```
private BufferedImage getBIFromIntArr(int[][] matrix){

    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(matrix.length * 4, matrix[0].length, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    - Gather the pixels in the form of [alpha, r, g, b]
    - multiply the size of the array by 4 for the model
    int[] pixels = new int[(matrix.length * 4 * matrix[0].length)];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; j++) {
            int pixel = matrix[i][j];
            pixels[index] = pixel;
            index++;
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                pixels[index] = 0;
                index++;
            }
        }
    }
    -get the raster
    WritableRaster raster = img.getRaster();
    -output the amount of pixels and a sample of the array
    System.out.println(pixels.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(pixels[i] + " ");
    }
   - set the pixels of the raster
    raster.setPixels(0, 0, matrix.length, matrix[0].length, pixels);
    - paint the image via an external routing to check works (does not)
    p.panel.setNewImage(img);

    return img;
}
```

Here is my understanding. The ARGB Type consists of 4 values Alpha, Red, Green, and Blue. I am *guessing* that setting the alpha values in the new BufferedImage to the greyscale image int values (the matrix values passed in) then this will reproduce the image. Please correct me if I am wrong. So as you can see I create an array of pixels that stores the int values like this: [intValue, 0, 0, 0] repeatedly to try to stay with the 4 value model.

Then I create a writable raster and set the gathered pixels in it using the gathered pixels. The only thing is that I get nothing in the BufferedImage. No error with the code below and Im sure my indeces are correct.

What am I doing wrong? Im sure it is obvious but any help is appreciated because I cant see it. Perhaps my assumption about the model is wrong?

Thanks,
Chronic